# Business Objects Report Navigation

Tags: charts, report, dashboard, business-objects

I've created a dashboard in Business Objects with two simple pie charts that show ticket information. When in Reading mode I want to be able to click the chart or some type of button that will automatically navigate me to another report with a table that has more detailed information about the tickets. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to do that using Drill Down.I usually just create two report tabs. One is labeled "Charts" or "Summary" and the other labeled "Tables" or "Detail." The end users seem to figure it out just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Webi, you can select there to allow you to hover over the details and also will allow you to click on the dashboard to open the details.